# Yup is not validating a checkbox when the user clicks the submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have the follow Yup configuration in my React app:

```
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string()
            .email('E-mail is not valid!')
            .required('E-mail is required!'),
        password: yup.string()
            .min(6, 'Password has to be longer than 6 characters!')
            .required('Password is required!'),
        tandc: yup.boolean()
            .oneOf([true], "You must accept the terms and conditions")
    })
```

My form looks like this (using Formik):

```
 <Form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Email
                        <Field type="email" name="email" className="form-control" />
                        </label>
                        <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label >Password
                        <Field type="password" name="password" className="form-control"  />
                        </label>
                        <ErrorMessage name="password" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">

                        <Field type="checkbox" name="tandc" className="form-check-input"  id="tandc" />
                        <ErrorMessage name="tandc" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                        <label htmlFor="tandc" >I agree to the Terms and Conditions
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <PrimaryButton label="Login" disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </PrimaryButton>
                </Form>
```

If the user clicks submit on the form, Yup validates the email and password field but ignores the checkbox field:

[image]

I can only get the checkbox validation to work if I first check and then uncheck the terms and conditions.

How do I make it work so that it shows the error message when the user clicks just the submit button?

Comment: `.required`, I guess?

Comment: I tried required and it made no difference

Comment: This [comment](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/415#issuecomment-579646204) says "if you're using it with formik make sure you set initialValues = {termsOfService: false}"

Comment: @GennadyDogaev you are correct. I need to set an initial value, add it as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: just add `.oneOf([true])`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/415#issuecomment-579646204) in Yup repository,

> if you're using it with formik make sure you set `initialValues = {termsOfService: false}`

Answer (score 30):

For

```
yup.boolean().oneOf([true],'Message');
```

to work you have to set the initial value of that field to `true` or `false`.

In your case it would look something like this

`tandc : false`

wherever you are setting the initial values

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/):

```js
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
        ...
    tandc: yup.bool() // use bool instead of boolean
        .oneOf([true], "You must accept the terms and conditions")
 })
```

credits: [Jason Watmore](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/04/29/react-hook-form-7-required-checkbox-example)

Comment: Why the end of line after *"terms and"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen i don't understand your question.

Comment: Additionally, .required() helped me as well

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
yup.default(false)
```

or

```js
yup.default(true)
```

to specify default value

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 